# Single lock object or multiple lock object for thread synchronization in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a class which has a few dictionary objects and other data that  needs to be protected. These are manipulated by multiple threads (both read and write). I am not sure about should I use single lock object to lock all  or each data should have different lock?  In my case slow performance is preferable than dead lock.

```
    static object object1 = new object();
    static object object2 = new object();
    private Queue<Change> changeNotifications = new Queue<Change>();
    private Dictionary<string, IConnectionClient> connectionClients1 = new Dictionary<string, IConnectionClient>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    private Dictionary<string, IConnectionClient> connectionClients2 = new Dictionary<string, IConnectionClient>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

    public static void ThreadFunction1()
    {
        lock (object1)
        {
            //update connectionClients2
        }
    }

    public static void ThreadFunction2()
    {
        lock (object2)
        {
            //access changeNotifications
            //update connectionClients1
        }
    }
```

My question can I use single locking object with lock?

Comment: Can you guarantee that both  ThreadFunction1 and ThreadFunction2 will never be called at the same time?

Comment: @jdweng Why would they need any such guarantee?

Comment: Without knowing how the data is used, and how it's allowed to be used from the various threads, the question is unanswerable.  We can't know if it's acceptable for different dictionaries to be used at the same time or not.  It will depend on what they actually do and contain.

Comment: The question is answered if you can guarantee the two threads methods will NEVER be called simultaneously.  But with threads I do not think you can guarantee both methods will never be called at the same time.

Comment: @jdweng Sure, you don't need to synchronize the code again if the caller is already doing the synchronization for you.  It seems unlikely someone would ask about how to have a class handle synchronization if they were expecting the caller to always be doing the synchronization for them.

Comment: I have no control on these functions when those are called. Those are called  due to external events

Comment: Why not just use the concurrent collections unless/until you've established that they're not working for you? Why start with "I need to throw locks at this problem"?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever   I can't use concurrent collections because these are old code which I have maintenance responsibility. To change it too much work for me.

Comment: @Servy : The question was if they needed two lock objects.

Comment: @jdweng Yes.  That means you need to know whether or not it would be safe for code using one object to run concurrently with code using the other.  It might be, or it might not be, depending on what the code is doing, what the objects are, etc.  You seem to be just assuming that it's not valid for them ever (by implying that something else would need to synchronize them if this code didn't), which isn't necessarily true.  If they really are entirely unrelated, there's nothing wrong with the two methods running concurrently.

Answer (score 1):

Using a single lock is the safe, but potentially slow, approach.

If your resources are independent, then by all means use a separate lock for each of them.

If you ever need to acquire multiple locks, make sure you always acquire them in the same order to prevent the possibility of deadlock.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! Although the performance will take a hit, this is very possible.

However, to remain robust and flexible I would create a thread safe, [atomic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearizability) wrapper class around your desired objects that must be accessible via multi-threading (in this case the `Dictionary`). This will encapsulate the locking *within* the object, thus allowing thread safety to be handled in a cleaner way and abstracted away from future development.

To do so, one approach could be with your one lock idea! Ensure that all mutable fields in the object are wrapped with the lock and your application will work as desired. A more performance-driven approach is to utilize a lock per variable.

Although plausible, it does yield the question as to why you are multi-threading in the first place. With the use of one lock, this tells me that either you have few fields being protected (which in that case one lock is a valid approach), you are uncomfortable with multi-threading (completely valid, most people are) or you are attempting to lock lengthy operations. Locking should be minimized to short, smaller operations to prevent unnecessary thread waiting, overusing computer resources, and actually reducing performance to lower than a single-threaded approach.